# Abuse of notation ? $(A\mid M_{n\times p})$ to denote a set of matrices...

Tags: matrices, notation

Let $A\in M_{n\times m}$. Would it be considered an abuse of notation to write

$$\left(A\mid M_{n\times p}\right)\subseteq M_{n\times (m+p)},\tag{1}$$

where $\mid$ denotes matrix augmentation ? By $\left(A\mid M_{n\times p}\right)$ I mean the set of all matrices in $M_{n\times(m+p)}$ whose "left side" submatrix is exactly $A$, which is itself fixed.

Comment: If, I would write $\subseteq$ instead of $\in$. But you should explain it in text anyway.

Comment: Ah yes i see as they're both sets of matrices.

Comment: If $(A|M_{n\times p})$ is a subset, and possibly $(M_{n\times m}|B)$ is a subset, then what to think about $(A|B)$? Is it a subset or a matrix? It looks a bit like $2$ and $\{2\}$, same, but different.

Comment: A matrix in $M_{n\times (m+q)}$ where $q $ is the number of columns of $B $, so long as $B $ has $n $ rows. At least that's what I'd want it to be...

Comment: @A.G. Good point !